# MAUI WebView GeolocationEnabled

Tags: maui

I'm trying to use maui webView to load a map.
how to use  `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to get location?

Android and kotlin has the same implementation。

Answer (score -1):

You and use the code to get the location:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancelTokenSource;
private bool _isCheckingLocation;

public async Task GetCurrentLocation()
{
    try
    {
        _isCheckingLocation = true;

        GeolocationRequest request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Location location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request, _cancelTokenSource.Token);

        if (location != null)
            Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
    }
   
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Unable to get location
    }
    finally
    {
        _isCheckingLocation = false;
    }
}

public void CancelRequest()
{
    if (_isCheckingLocation && _cancelTokenSource != null && _cancelTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested == false)
        _cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Here is the website which you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/geolocation?tabs=ios

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Your code is for C# call, not for JavaScript call.